# React Native, iOS bundling failed: useUnicodeFlag is not a valid regexpu-core option

Tags: react-native, expo

```
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/Data/parseLogBoxLog.js:
/Users/rakshithkumars/Number-Guessing/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/Data/parseLogBoxLog.js: 
.useUnicodeFlag is not a valid regexpu-core option.
```

Comment: You need to add more info like env data, full crash logs, version of the packages, etc.

Answer (score 11):

I fixed it in this way:

Run:

`yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex --dev`

or

`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex`

Then open you `babel.config.js` file, which may be something like this:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

And add this line:

```
plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex'],
```

It should end up something like this:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex'],
  };
};
```

Note:
This shouldn't change anything, but, before trying this change, I migrated from Node 14 to Node 16. Should not affect, but... Mentioning it just in case.

Note 2:
It was not necessary to run `expo r -c` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue and fixed it by adding the following plugin to `babel.config.js`:

```
@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex
```

Then ran `expo r -c` to clear the cache